# Pushing data from database to UI in realtime

Tags: mongodb, redis, real-time, server-sent-events, real-time-updates

I have a database (MySQL) to which data is being written to. I need to push new records and changed records to UI. A few constraints here: I do not have control on the code which writes to this database and I cannot modify it to write to a queue.

So far, I am reading the DB periodically for changes and new additions (using a last update timestamp) and pushing that data to a mongo db (as I do not want to hit main MySQL server for every request). Then I push these changes to frontend using cramp (ruby framework) and server sent events. To maintain per user queue, I have redis in the mix.

I realize that this is a convulated way of doing realtime push. I was wondering if there is a more neat solution to this mess.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to push data realtime from the server, then make use of technologies that provide real time access. I would recommend you to make use of [Websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

The only issue is websockets is not supported by all the browsers, to take care of this you can use the available frameworks built over websockets that provide fallback to protocols supported by the browsers such as long polling, streaming etc. Following are the frameworks which I would suggest to use:

- Atmosphere framework - https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere
- Play framework! - http://www.playframework.org/

Comment: am already using SSE which is better for my use case than websockets.